# Tkinter: OptionMenu Drop down list positioning control on multiple screens

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program, which runs on two displays - secondary screen is a video feed, the primary screen is a Tkinter GUI on a touch screen.

In the GUI are multiple drop down lists, some have a significant amount of contents (50+). These, if pressed, show the drop down list on the secondary screen, not on the primary (which is the touch screen).

How can I ensure the drop down lists, independently of the amount of items, appear on the primary screen (limited view with scroll arrows OK)?
(Problem does not appear on lists with less than 30 items)

[Problem Description Principle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI8u5.png)

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed') ##ensure GUI full screen on primary screen
.....................
popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *data)
popupMenu.config(font=helv36, width=12)
menu = root.nametowidget(popupMenu.menuname) ##thanks to martineau
menu.config(font=helv36)
popupMenu.grid(row = 8, column =0, sticky='nw')
tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround to the Problem I raised.
To avoid the problem described, I re-arranged the displays in the OS display setting menu next to each other, not on top of each other.
By doing so, the drop down list is now shown for all instances on the correct primary screen.
If somebody still knows how to actively place in Tkinter the drop down list on a specific screen, please let me know. Thanks!